# RNFirebaseAdMobPackage throws error in react-native version 0.60.4

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I just upgraded my React Native application to version `0.60.4`. Here i'm trying to add `react-native-firebase` version `^5.2.3` and facing the following error:

[image]

I have tried replacing

```
import io.invertase.firebase.RNFirebaseAdMobPackage;
```

With

```
import io.invertase.firebase.RNFirebasePackage;
```

And

```
new RNFirebaseAdMobPackage();
```

With

```
new RNFirebasePackage();
```

in `PackageList.java`. But so far no luck. What else can i do to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Check the settings in order.

- In order for Android to parse this file, add the google-services
  gradle plugin as a dependency to your project in the project level
  `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
  // ...
  dependencies {
    // ...
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
  }
}
```

1. To apply the plugin to your project, add the following to the VERY
   BOTTOM of your app `android/app/build.gradle` file:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

2. The Firebase modules need to be installed as project dependencies.
   In the `android/app/build.gradle` file, add the following:

```
    dependencies {
      // This should be here already
      implementation project(':react-native-firebase')

      // Firebase dependencies
      implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
      implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9"

      ...
```

3. Due to some breaking changes in v12+ of the Android Firebase
   libraries, you'll need to upgrade your Gradle version to at least
   v4.4 and make a few other tweaks as follows:

1) In `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`, update the gradle URL to `gradle-4.4-all.zip`
2) In `android/build.gradle` check that you have `google()` specified in the buildScript repositories section:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()  // <-- Check this line exists and is above jcenter
        jcenter()
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

3) In `android/build.gradle` update Android build tools to version `3.4.1`:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
```

Google Play services from `11.2.0` onwards require their dependencies to be downloaded from Google's Maven respository so add the required reference to the repositories section of the project level `build.gradle` (android/build.gradle):

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google() // <-- Add this line above jcenter
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

- When using `react-native-firebase` with Proguard enabled
     (minifyEnabled true in `android/app/build.gradle`) you need to update
     your `proguard-rules.pro` file (`android/app/proguard-rules.pro`) to
     include the following lines:

  -keep class io.invertase.firebase.** { *; }

  -dontwarn io.invertase.firebase.**

The `RNFirebasePackage` only provides your application with access to Core features. Check out the installation guides on the other modules for how to use other Firebase features.

**Please check if there is this part.**

```
dependencies {
  // ...
  implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.2.1"
}
```

```java
import io.invertase.firebase.admob.RNFirebaseAdMobPackage; // <-- this line
...
ew RNFirebaseAdMobPackage() // <-- this line
```

```xml
<application ...>

  <!-- this line as part of new AdMob library process. Sample AdMob App ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
  <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
    android:value="YOUR_ADMOB_APP_ID"/>

  <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>  <!-- this line to avoid crashes on Android 9 until AdMob SDK update -->

</application>
```

Comment: Adding implementations in app/build.gradle throws error for adding depecdency manually in version 0.60.4. Any other way to do that? @hongdevelop

Comment: No while running the application i'm getting this error for for adding dependency manually and telling to unlink the dependency.

Comment: I did this: cd android && gradlew clean && cd .. && react-native run-android and now i'm back with the same RNFirebaseAdMobPackage error. @hongdevelop

Comment: @TanmoySarker I think the package remains in the Android file.

Comment: So, how do i remove that?

Comment: @TanmoySarker  I updated the check item in the answer.

Comment: Doing so gives the following error now:  > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-firebase.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-firebase:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

Comment: Then, add an adobe package like my answer. Just follow what you've checked.

Comment: same error facing from last 10 days.When trying to upgrade react-native version 0.55 to 0.63. :(