# error: cannot find symbol class RNFirebaseAdMobPackage

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, admob

was anyone able to solve this issue. I have all the dependencies needed and I followed the instructions:
https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/admob/android

[RNFirebaseAdMobPackage throws error in react-native version 0.60.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57250177/rnfirebaseadmobpackage-throws-error-in-react-native-version-0-60-4/57257118#57257118)

but for some reason still getting this error when trying to build the app on android studio or on the Terminal using react-native run-android
the error appears on the file 
app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/PackageList.java

Removing the Admobpackage dependency didn't help as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be sure to check the compatibility of your **react native** version in your `package.json` as well as your **google play services** sdk number in your project `build.gradle` so that they follow the chart here
https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/getting-started#Supported-versions---React-Native-/-Firebase
[image]

99% of my inexplicable hair pulling frustrating random errors with react-native-firebase are related to following this chart properly. One other thing that fixed one of my most baffling of errors was by adjusting my Gradle build version to a previous version that worked. Build -> Clean project as well as restarting Android studio is never a bad idea.

Good luck!

Comment: This is worked! the issue was that I was using 3.3.x with a 0.60 RN. Thank you so much!